# Update value inside angular js function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The controller.js file is given as

```
function XYZController($rootScope,$scope){
    var vm = this;
    vm.a = 0;
    var change = function(data){
        data.forEach(function(e,i){
            vm.a+=Number(e.value);
        });
    }
    $log.log(vm.a);
}
```

The function change is called,but the $log.log(a) prints 0,instead of the updated sum.How to take the updated value of vm.a?When I do $scope.$apply,I get an error "$digest is already in progress".

Comment: How do you call `change`? Please post all the relevant code.

Comment: if you are using ng-click, then you don't have to call $apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `$log.log(vm.a);` before calling `change()`, therefore it logs your `vm.a = 0;`, if you change your code to this it should work.

```
function XYZController($rootScope,$scope){
    var vm = this;
    vm.a = 0;
    var change = function(data){
        data.forEach(function(e,i){
            vm.a+=Number(e.value);
        });
        $log.log(vm.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly, javascript is synchronous.

Comment: The value will be changed, and it will also be usable outside of your function. Why'd you assume that wouldn't be possible ?

Comment: Thanks,it changed.I was just wasting time trying to print the updated value,outside the function,without checking if it actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call $log before the completion of your change function else it will return you 0 only.